# Eclipse egit : How to synchronize with remote repo?

Tags: eclipse, git, version-control, egit

I am new to GIT and I used to commit to my local copy and then "push" to remote repository.
Recently I modified my code from another computer and wanted to synchronize changes with my home-computer.

But in the git synchronise view , after I mark files as "Mark as merged"(after resolving changes with local changes) how can I commit back to the remote repository ? (like in SVN?)

(ie: even I click "Mark as Merged" the "red double-array icons" stays the same)
[Click for larger size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdGU2.png)

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't use synchronize that much because I use the following workflow:

```
- fetch
- merge
  * resolved merges are sent to git index
  * unresolved merges need to be fixed
- add fixed merge to index
- commit
- push
```

Comment: so one has to commit and push after fetching/pulling changes from a remote repository? even if one didn't make any changes in the local copy, but the remote copy changed through other contributions?

Comment: if you don't change anything locally you won't have to commit, if you change something then a merge will produce and you will have to commit the merge result

Answer (score 4):

Mark as merged means added in the index after conflict resolution.

You need to commit and push.
See "[Committing a merge](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Committing_a_merge)" in the Egit manual.